# Error in Ubuntu Server for service bind9

Tags: dns, services, reboot

Error in service bind9 when I'm starting

[image]

```
root@ServerRedes:~# service binder status  
  named.service - BIND Domain Name Server 
    Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)  
    Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-21 23:13:37 UTC; 13s ago 
      Docs: man: named (8) 
   Process: 784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
       CPU: 36ms  
 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at> 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server. 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly. m
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.  
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server. 
root@ServerRedes:~# service bind9 status 
  named.service - BIND Domain Name Server 
     Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/named.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled) 
     Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2023-03-21 23:13:37 UTC; 25s ago 
       Docs: man: named (8) 
    Process: 784 ExecStart=/usr/sbin/named $OPTIONS (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE) 
        CPU: 36ms 

mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at> 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: Stopped BIND Domain Name Server. 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Start request repeated too quickly. 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: named.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'. 
mar 21 23:13:37 ServerRedes systemd[1]: Failed to start BIND Domain Name Server.
```

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release details (*details in the title should also exist in your question text as not all users of the site use large screens & modern browsers & title may not be viewable!*) just provide a statement and link.  Do you have a question for your *unstated* OS?

Comment: You haven't provided any of your configuration files for us to be able to try to help.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text. Cut and paste into the body of the question so it can be easily read, searched and no info is cut off.